# In python curses, how i can get string from user and print on the screen in same time

Tags: python, ncurses

I used the **curses** library in Python to divide the screen into two part, the first half to print a set of strings and the second half to get the user input by using **getstr()** , but when the user enters the ipnut **curses** interrupt the entry and clear the user's entries

```
def main(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    stdscr.nodelay(1)
    stdscr.timeout(100)
    i = 0
    while 1 :
        i = i+1
        stdscr.addstr(0,0,"frame"+str(i))

        curses.echo()    
        user_input = stdscr.getstr(5,0)

        stdscr.addstr(7,0,user_input)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

`getstr` won't help with this.  If you want to concurrently update the screen and get input, you'll have to make a function like `getstr`, using `getch`, and allowing the `getch` calls to time-out (to do the `addstr` calls periodically).

The [`nodelay`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.nodelay) function can help with this, though using that tends to use too much processing time.  It's usually preferable to use [`timeout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.timeout), e.g., 10-20 milliseconds.